# widget price filter won't work with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

[image: Slider]

My goal is to filter the products without having to click the filter button. (I'm using wordpress)
`the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Price_Filter')`

First, I was thinking of using mouseout function on jQuery, by triggering the Filter button on mouseout.

Unfortunately, I can't make jquery trigger the slider.

To make this simple, I just wanted to make the elements(sliders) hide first.

```
$('.widget_price_filter .ui-slider .ui-slider-handle:last-child').hide();
$('.widget_price_filter').hide();
$('span.widget_price_filter.ui-slider.ui-slider-handle:last-child').hide();
```

but no luck. None of the sliders hides.

Apparently, when I add this via css.

```
.widget_price_filter .ui-slider .ui-slider-handle:last-child {
display: none;
}
```

This hides the slider handle. So I know I'm targetting the right classes. Is there a way to trigger these sliders via jquery or javascript?

I know this is not the best way to accomplish this. So I am also open to other recommendation to do this.

This is the code produced by the `the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Price_Filter')`

```
<div class="widget woocommerce widget_price_filter">
    <form method="get" action="http://site.local/shop/">
        <div class="price_slider_wrapper">
            <div class="price_slider ui-slider ui-slider-horizontal ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" style="">
                <div class="ui-slider-range ui-widget-header ui-corner-all" style="left: 0%; width: 100%;"></div>
                <span class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" style="left: 0%;"></span>
                <span class="ui-slider-handle ui-state-default ui-corner-all" tabindex="0" style="left: 100%;"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="price_slider_amount">
                <input type="text" id="min_price" name="min_price" value="1" data-min="1" placeholder="Min price" style="display: none;">
                <input type="text" id="max_price" name="max_price" value="25" data-max="25" placeholder="Max price" style="display: none;">
                <button type="submit" class="button">Filter</button>
                <div class="price_label" style="">
                    Price: <span class="from">$1</span> — <span class="to">$25</span>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Right! I updated my post, it is WordPress.

Comment: *"it is WordPress"* is meaningless. That doesn't tell us anything about the code behind this filter widget. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: so add a change handler to the input?

Comment: Provide rather HTML. About filtering - you should use `$('.widget_price_filter').on('change', function(event){})`

Comment: @Zydnar - I thought this was going to fix the issue too. But it didn't work.

Comment: @AdrianRoyBaguio I can't see you're HTML, so maybe it's about other element, but for sliders I always use change event.

Comment: I updated my post above. I added the code produced by `the_widget( 'WC_Widget_Price_Filter')`

@Zydnar, this didn't work either $('.widget_price_filter').on('click', 'span', function(event){});

Comment: @AdrianRoyBaguio try example from official docs: https://jqueryui.com/slider/#range here are used change handlers: https://jqueryui.com/slider/#colorpicker

Comment: Got it to work...

$('.price_slider').on('mouseout', function(event){
   $('.price_slider_amount button.button').trigger( "click" );
  });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.price_slider').on('mouseout', function(event){
 $('.price_slider_amount button.button').trigger( "click" );
});
```

Thank you to sir @Zydnar. I realized that the WC_Widget_Price_Filter is created after the page load. Hence, .click() function alone will not work.

Therefore, the use on() function works and hurray it is now working!